# Where does Android save the information of the permissions granted to all the applications

Tags: android, permissions

Where does Android save the information of the permissions granted to all the applications?
i mean the permissions granted to applications during installation

Answer (score 0):

After instalation, if you go to `settings > aplications > click on application` and you can see below what permissions are granted to it.

If you want to know a litle more about manage aplication permissions, you got a good article [here](http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/07/25/app-ops-android-4-3s-hidden-app-permission-manager-control-permissions-for-individual-apps/)

Comment: hi thanks for the reply, i'm familiar with this article. i wanted to know where does android system stores this information, on which file/database/storage is the per application permissions information is saved?

Comment: I think that information is private, you cant access it directly unless you have ROOT access to your device. By the way, check this topic if it can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19487770/3640637

Comment: i don't need to access it, i just need to know where it is saved for a paper i'm writing

Comment: When i mean "cant access it" is more likely "it doesnt exist as a file or directory". If you find anything more about this topic post it. gl for your paper

Comment: does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Android does not store it extra. Android installs your apk file. The permissions are in the apk file in the manifest part. No need to store them again. Well thats what i think.

Comment: yes but what happens when your application wants to preform an action that requires a certain permission? Then in run time android will check your manifest?

Comment: Good question. But i do not know. Interesting though!