# Sharing files and data between apps on android - intents +

Tags: android, android-intent, filesystems

[Permission of app specific folder on external storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487770/permission-of-app-specific-folder-on-external-storage)

I want to open files and share files using automation,  on a rooted device,  so newly created media in app_a is opened in app_b, even when apps provide no option to configure the output directory,  so data is in a folder in data/ directory

Example source location (and permissions, in case that's an optional workaround hack:)
Not even sure how to copy path (using TotalCommander)
[image]

Some related info in answer to question here, about options to share content (files) between apps, **on rooted device**,  and any options where root not required...

> b. For simple, small chunks of data, I suggest you go the
> Intent/BroadcastReceiver approach.
>
> c. You can go the ContentProvider approach is you wanna do things the
> right way.
>
> d. You can go the Intent/Service approach.
>
> e. For true IPC - use AIDL.

[image]

To use intents does the app need to have registered for it? Or are some/all implicit intents available for all apps?

These are the intents found for the app I want to open files in - does that tell you whether the Broadcast/ ContentProvider/ Service options are available?

Also I'd like to open files from app/files in /android folder, is this a job for su or chmod, or will that not work / be a very bad idea?

Looking into options b-e, gathering requirements and limitations, for data sharing on rooted and non-rooted devices.

For existing apps (as oppose to developer info for building apps, if there's a diff)

Comment: You wrote an unreadable post. Sorry. If you had only said here -full path- is my file, how to share it to other apps.. ?